# Save Position of dragged items with Dragula Drag and Drop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dragula, react-dragula

I'm using react-dragula to drag and drop cards. I need to save it after dragging it. How should I save the cards position after drag and drop?

This is the function.

```
const dragDropRow1 = (componentBackingInstance) => {
    if (componentBackingInstance) {
      let options = { };
      Dragula([componentBackingInstance], options);
        console.log("find1", options)
        console.log("find2", componentBackingInstance)
        console.log("find3", dragDropRow1)
    }
};
```

This is how I use the function in the body.

```
<Grid container ref={dragDropRow1} spacing={2} className="dragdrop-container">
```

This is the cards I'm using in the body.

```
< Typography variant = "subtitle1"
component = "h2"
className = "widget-title" > {
    getLabel({
      module: "frontOfficerDashboard",
      label: "opd appointments"
    })
  } <
  /Typography> <
  Box className = "widget-table" >
  <
  Box display = "flex" >
  <
  Box flexGrow = {
    1
  } >
  <
  Typography variant = "body2"
component = "p"
className = "color-primary" > {
    getLabel({
      module: "frontOfficerDashboard",
      label: "today total"
    })
  } <
  /Typography> <
  /Box>
```

Comment: This is a link to codepen which contains the complete code. - https://codepen.io/vinulak/pen/OJbRgvr

Comment: Sorry but I find your code rather unreadable. And I wouldn't turn the prose into quotes either.

Comment: Is this code in https://codepen.io/vinulak/pen/OJbRgvr unreadable too?